# React native codepush updates effecting startup time of react native app

Tags: react-native, startup, code-push, react-native-code-push

My app is opening in 3 seconds on 2gb ram mobiles when there is no codepush implemented in the app, when codepush is present and when codepush downloading the updates, from next restart the app is taking 15 to 20 seconds to open, before showing splashscreen it is showing white screen for 15 to 20 seconds, there is some issue in codepush, can anyone tell me how this can be resolved?

i tried to kept codepush and i am expecting the app to be open in 3 seconds even when updates are installed for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the --use-hermes option for appcenter-cli. Somehow it is a secret undocumented weapon.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/2448#issuecomment-1683473610